# Theoretic question about game programming using SFML

Tags: sfml

I have read whole tutorial section on `sfml-dev.org` and have some question.

- What are exactly views and how to use them ?
- Should I render things in views or in renderwindow ?

Comment: Try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 5):

Views are like a 2D cameras. Those describe that which section do you see (what parts will be in the window) of that you render.

View is not something like you render into. You should render in a RenderWindow, and use view(s) to control the visible part of the rendered "world".

Comment: There even more tutorials on the GitHub wiki. A few month ago I've written a tutorial specially about `sf::Views`, to give some intuition: [Using `sf::View`](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Using-View)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you this tuto, I found it really useful:
http://dev.my-gate.net/2012/06/using-sfview/

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.